# is it possible to reload postgresql idle_in_transaction_session_timeout config without restart

Tags: postgresql

I want to change `idle_in_transaction_session_timeout` parameter in PostgreSQL 13, then I execute this sql:

```
alter system set idle_in_transaction_session_timeout='30min';
```

when I show the new set value, it still the old value, seems it did not take effect right now, because the PostgreSQL was  online, so is it possible to make the alter take effect without restart the PostgreSQL? My PostgreSQL was deployment in kubernetes cluster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to reload PostgreSQL:

```
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```